# Undo removed prediction in swiftkey android app

Tags: sms, swiftkey

I have by mistakenly removed some predicted texts and confused how can i get them back ? this has happened without my awareness when the phone was in pocket without display lock.

I have lost many of my words and finding it very hard to text using swift key nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

swiftkey stores personalized predictions in the sd card but probabily in a hidden file. in order to change your predictions I think you should reset your typing data under Advanced in the app. afterwards, you have to re-teach your expressions (3-4 times the same words).

hope this helps

Comment: i re installed swiftkey and it worked charm!